# java message bundle - property file naming convention when using variants?

Tags: java, locale

what is the naming convention for message bundle property files when using variants?

for instance, if the locale is EN US, the property file lookup will be

message_en_US.properties

though, what if I instantiate a local EN US though the variant string is "DEVL"

what is the search order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) suggests the following:

```
baseName + "_" + language1 + "_" + country1 + "_" + variant1
```